# T SQL Delete records based on a calculated field

Tags: t-sql

I want to delete rows in my table where the answer for 6 fields is zero / null:

```
Delete
from TableA
WHERE (a + b + c + d + e + f) IS NULL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE T FROM
  dbo.TableA T
  WHERE COALESCE(a, 0) + 
        COALESCE(b, 0) + 
        COALESCE(c, 0) +
        COALESCE(d, 0) +
        COALESCE(e, 0) +
        COALESCE(f, 0) = 0
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b67bf/1)

Comment: What if there are non null rows that are all zero?

Comment: @bendataclear the question says zero or null, my answer will work in either case

Answer (score 2):

```
 WHERE COALESCE((a + b + c + d + e + f), 0) = 0
```

or

```
 WHERE NULLIF((a + b + c + d + e + f), 0) IS NULL
```

No need to have this for every column

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to delete those rows then you can use query like

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE (a + b + c + d + e + f) IS NULL OR (a + b + c + d + e + f) = 0
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean if al fields are null or if 1 or more field is null?

It may be as simple as:

```
delete
from TableA
WHERE (a + b + c + d + e + f) IS NULL
```

Comment: If the sum of all fields are null / zero

Comment: @wilest, If one of the fields is null then it will return null even if the rest all have values.